# Importing PySimpleGUI window variable to another file

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm writing an app using PySimpleGUI and PyTube. I have code like this in `file1.py`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):      

        layout = [[sg.Text('My one-shot window.')],      
                     [sg.InputText()],      
                     [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]      

        window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)    

        event, values = window.read()    
        window.close()
```

and I want to use `window` in function located in `file2.py`.

```py
def func(): 
    window['-key-'].update_bar()
```

How should I import it properly so that I could use it like in the function above which is in `file2.py`?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: How is `func()` being called?  Perhaps you can simply pass `window` to it as a parameter, assuming that the call is being made from some place in file1 where that variable is in scope.  (You can't `import` it, as it's a local variable.)

Comment: I’m using it in another function in `file2.py`:
`yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=func)`
It’s function that downloads video from YouTube with PyTube.

Comment: `window` in your code is local to the `__init__` function and cannot be accessed elsewhere.  (There's really no point in making that a class.)  You could make it a member variable (`self.window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)`, and then do `import file1` in file2, and use `file1.gui.window['--key-'].update_bar()`, or whatever you called the Gui instance in file1.

Comment: Would the outcome be the same if I created another function in `Gui` other than  `__init__` and put the code from it right there?

Answer (score 0):

In file1.py:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):      

        layout = [[sg.Text('My one-shot window.')],      
                     [sg.InputText()],      
                     [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]      

        window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)    

        event, values = window.read()    
        window.close()
```

In file2.py:

```
from file1 import Gui # Import the class Gui from file1
def func(): 
    gui = Gui() # Create an object (named gui) of the class (Gui)
                # (which in turn creates the window through the __init__ function)

    gui.window['-key-'].update_bar() # Here you may use the attribute (window) of the object (gui)

func() # Call the func
```

Make sure to create a `__init__.py` file in the same directory where `file1.py` and `file2.py` are located. This sets the current directory as a user created package which in turn helps with the import statement in `file2.py`.
the gui object is created